# Why does the word "shop" behave like a non-count noun in phrases like "set up shop"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

The word "shop" seems to behave like a non-count noun in phrases like "set up shop", "shut up shop" and "close up shop". There's no article ("a"), no plural ending ("-s"). Dictionaries, such as [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shop) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shop) only list count usages and singular usages (as in "the shop"), so this idiomatic usage of the word "shop" appears to be very unique to these phrases, because the word doesn't seem to have common non-idiomatic non-count usages at all. In comparison, take the word "business", which has both common non-idiomatic non-count usages ("get down to business", "bad for business") and count usages ("small businesses").

So why does the word "shop" have this non-count usage in the phrases above? Etymologically or historically, was there any point at which "shop" meant "business", but such a non-count usage only survived in the idioms, while only the count usages survive elsewhere?

Comment: Usages, not nouns, are best described as count or non-count. Thus 'coffee' in 'My favourite drink has to be coffee' is a non-count usage, whereas 'The two principal coffees (= types/species of coffee) are arabica and robusta' and 'Three coffees (= mugs etc of coffee) please' (or 'One tea, please') are count usages. // This is certainly not a count usage, though I'd prefer to analyse 'set up shop' as an idiom, or at least a set phrase, without analysing further. Compare 'weigh anchor' and 'break camp'. Related idioms / set phrases involving 'shop' are  _talk shop, play shop, all over the shop_.

Comment: For non-count nouns like "coffee" and "beer", dictionaries tend to list count uses as "a cup/glass of coffee/beer" to convey individual units, portions or pieces as opposed to substance. Whereas "shops" are generally individual units rather than a "substance". Maybe "shop" was once used as an abstract concept, like "work" or something, and that use stuck in these phrases?

Comment: The question "In English, why does ...?" is frequently unanswerable, other than to say, "Because." As an aside, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shop) includes two examples of another non-count usage: *I am taking shop this semester. / I made a table in shop.* NB "very unique" is allowable, but grading an absolute will invite argument. :-)

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw Saying _coffee_ is a non-count noun is like saying that _grow_ is an intransitive verb. Dictionaries correctly label _usages_ as count / non-count; transitive / intransitive.

Comment: @Chappo I checked the LDOCE and apparently the non-count noun "shop" (as in the example "I am taking shop this semester") is short for "shop class", which is used in American English to refer to school subjects for dealing with tools and machinery (per the Merriam-Webster page, "the art or science of working with tools and machinery"). But does it have anything to do with "shop" as in "set up shop", though?

Comment: I'm sure the usages are related. I would interpret *shop* in "set up shop" as meaning *business* (although the idiom is also used metaphorically), but I have no doubt it may in the past have been broader and included manufacturing/trades. The term *shop steward* is still understood in Aust and UK as meaning trade union representative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You wouldn't (in the US, at least) say "set up office".

Comment: It's not etymology, but phraseology.

Comment: *to go aship, to board ship*, analoguously *to set up a shop* > *to set up shop*?

Comment: @Chappo The word "shop" is still used for productive, non-retail places of work, that is 'workshops'. Thus you get "machine shops", "body shops" and so on. If you work in an industrial or motor industry setting you will often hear people saying things like "I've sent it to the shop to be machined" or "It's in the shop now, you can have it in a couple of hours when the paint's dried". In neither of these cases is the speaker referring to a retail outlet.

Comment: @vectory I'd never heard of "phraseology". "Ship" is also a peculiar case, because there's the phrase "abandon ship".

Answer (score 3):

Merriam-Webster provides a dictionary definition for this phrase under its definition of [*set up*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set%20up) (search for "set up shop"):

> **set up shop**
>   : to start a business or activity in a particular place

As a set phrase (or idiom), it's an expression that isn't defined by any of its individual components, so analyzing the syntactical role of *shop* doesn't work well in this specific instance.

---

It's possible to break with the idiom and say that you're going to *set up **a** shop* or *set up **the** shop*, but that would be in relation to a specific, singular, situation, and it wouldn't have the same meaning as the phrase itself.

Comment: "As a set phrase (or idiom), it's an expression that isn't defined by any of its individual components" Sure, but I hoped to find the reason behind this usage, hence the "etymology" tag. I guess this is one of those things that you just accept without questions.

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw  It probably derives from something like 'Zeke set up _his_ shop in ...' x 100000 with the 'his' being dropped at some indeterminate point (or rather over a period) in history. Many idioms (especially those of the slight-departure-from-standard-grammar variety) resist etymological analysis.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an authoritative answer--which would have to be* blimey, I don't have the foggiest--*but a barely educated guess.*

English shop has a cognate in Low-German Schuppen, "shed", think *tool-shed*, *work-shop*; cp. *Bude* "abode, house, building; (coll.) construction work company". This is homophone with *Schuppen* "fish schales", originally a rare kind of **uncountable** pluraletantum, if I read that correctly (thus *die Schuppe* would be a back formation by analogy). I haven't seen these related by the root, but if I were pressed to find a connection, I'd say that *roof, cover* is the primary symbolism for *building* ("under my roof, under my table") and that fish scales are significantly reminiscent of roof-tiles. So, if shop was ever understood as a non-count noun, that must have been a while back, perhaps in an isolated dialect. It's odd at least insofar the modern genus is maskulin, *der Schuppen*, while *-en* usually implies *die* (plural noun) or *das* (nominalized verb).

Incidentally, Frisian was isolated for a long time, though I wouldn't take that alone as an argument. Rather compare *shovel*, Ger. *Schaufel*, also Schippe. Again there's something about the form. Comparing *Scheibe, Schicht, Schindel* or *Schiefer* would maybe go a bit too far though.

There's also what looks like a verb *schoppen*, chiefly in the noun *Frühschoppen* "early bar opening hours, a drink in the morning", and now it becomes uncertain--if it wasn't before. A *Schoppen* is a measure of liquid, half a pint, related to Fr. *chopin*, and eventually related to *schöpfen*, *scoop*. The problem is that *Schöpfer* "creator, god" draws the attention of this word. This in turn may relate to *schaffen* "to work, succeed, create, scape", *-schaft* "-scape, -ship, -hood" (Landschaft, Herrschaft, Gemeinshaft, Nachbarschaft ...). There' are *Schöffel*, *Chef*, *Schaffner*, *Schäfer*, that relate more or less. *Geschäft* means "business", *geschäftig* "busy".

There's also *shaft*, that gives me the peculiar image of a shop-keep opening the window lid (the shop?), proping it up with a shaft; Alternatively pulling the blinders aside (*Gardinen* is another pluraletantum). Cp. *Schaufenster* ("shop front", literally "viewing window" or "show window"), *Schaubude* "fare establishment", Ger. *Schotten, Luken, Klüsen* (closures in windows or ship-pipe-works), and very significantly *Laden* "shop", *Fenster-Laden* "window lid" (those on the outside; another unusual maskulin *-en* noun); also see En. ladle, Ger. *Schub-lade* "drawer" (as if a lid that is shoved), *laden* "to load", and perhaps *Umschlagplatz* "market?", *umschlagen* "to flip, to swap", *Klappe* "lid, that which flips and clips", *verklappen* "to distribute [waste]", *market*, probably via Etruscan *merx*, in my humble opinion related to PIE *mey- "to change". Which *Laden* was first, and how it relates to *shop* I can't say, but it looks like a loaded semantic correspondance.

PS: The image of a shop-front propped up like that of any fast food truck came when I searched for *scappa*--pretty much into the blue--which is Italian and relates to *escape*, which has an oddly uncertain etymology (to cloak, really?). This reminded me of fire-escape, ancient Anatolian buildings with the entry through the roof, and thus outlets over fire places in all kinds of buildings, thus *window*. *shaft* is an after thought.

Comment: Can't believe the upvote for that. If I have to do the nagging myself: DWDS mentions roof covering in relation to *Schuppen*, but with straw bundles, "*(s)keup-, *skeub(h)- ‘Büschel, Schopf, Quaste’". *scales* is indeed explained as something that flips over/off/up; *Fisch-Schuppe* is instead linked to *schaben* "scrape, shave, e.g. to clean fish", *skā̌b(h)-. Now it's obvious that "bushels of straw" could semantically derive of a verb c.a. "to cut", as much as a degree of measure would. However, I was implying a Germanic innovation, so in sum there is disagreement.

Comment: Synchronic grammar gives an easier explanation. *Shop* can be an abstract noun without a verb form--*shopping* is marked differently--that needs auxhilliaries, or it denotes *the* actual place, eg *all over the shop*--while *clean up [the] shop* is indecicive for me. Similarly *-ness, biznes* (*business*) is clearly marked. The diff is like for *experience* ~ *experiences*, "to have _ experience" ~ "to have had [\have been at] *an* experience". ... Noteworthy, cp. *scope*, after-all I indicated "windows", which but may be purely random coincidence. *It fell like scales from his eyes*, LOL.